# Why is Google My Business info not being displayed in SERPs?

Tags: google, google-my-business

We opened a new business 2 weeks ago in mid-June 2020. We set up a Google My Business account for it. Their first verification postcard never arrived, but a second try succeeded. We got the postcard and verified with them approximately one week ago.

We populated the My Business account with a lot of information, including all of the important fields.

Our Google My Business information is still not displaying on SERPs. Can anyone guess why not please?

When I log into Goggle My Business it says: "Your business is live on Google." When I click the link "View on Search" I get an SERP page with the My Business information displayed nicely. However, when I simply open a Google search page and type the same search term (the name of our business), no "My Business" info appears on the SERP!

A list of other "Places" showing competitors appears at the top, but we are not among the listings.

When I click the link that says "View on Maps" I get a maps page showing the business. But when I just open a new Google Maps page and search for our business, we are not there.

(Our business name is: New Paltz Equipment Rental. Our website is npequipmentrental.com)

Other notes: we have a web address, but our website is only one page so far, showing our name, logo, and a little about what we do, with our phone number, hours and an embedded Google map. The embedded Google map shows our address but does not show our business at the address.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that you are not only the one trying to rank for that term in your locality and thus other businesses are appearing in the results.

Now Google can't show them all in the first place so it will show some and the rest are shown on the maps page. (Which you say you are able to see your business there)

What this means is that you can't expect to outsmart all the hard work done by others by just creating a new business profile and take the 1st spot that easily.

Now for the steps that needs to be taken.

1. Do you have reviews for your business yet?
2. Have you added good description? By good I mean human readable (Don't go overboard with SEO and Keywords, keep it natural)
3. Try to update your website too. No one knows internal workings of Google Algo but it should help.
4. Wait for some months and maybe years. This is business we are talking about. Maybe they don't rank very new businesses up and above the old and established ones.

Comment: Thank you Keral. You misunderstood one minor point - we don't show up on Google maps either - but your answer makes sense and I'm sure that it is correct. Thank you for pointing us in the right direction.

Comment: If you are not appearing at all then it is definitely a problem. Sorry I thought you were just not appearing on the main page but digging deeper you were listed. My bad. But as you said you opened it up mid June so not much time has passed since. Maybe wait a little before taking any further action as it could be counter productive. If it still doesn't works out after a month please comment here and maybe some experiment shall be carried out. :)

Comment: Your website is not even appearing in normal search for me. I tried from different IPs too. Only thing that comes up is this thread and the one that that you started on Google itself.